# How to get China Stock Market Index (SSE) in Google Sheets using GOOGLEFINANCE?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-finance, google-sheets-formula

I have searched everywhere but didn't find a way for this.
It's for `=Googlefinance("ticker")`, Is china's SSE index available as a ticker for google finance, to be used in google sheets?

Answer (score 5):

did you try:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("SSE", "price")

=GOOGLEFINANCE("SSE", "all", TODAY()-7, TODAY(), "daily")

=GOOGLEFINANCE("SSE", "price", TODAY()-7, TODAY(), "daily")
```

[image]

---

or perhaps:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("LON:SSE", "price")

=GOOGLEFINANCE("LON:SSE", "all", TODAY()-7, TODAY(), "daily")
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/000001.SS/", "//*"), 
 "where Col1 contains '000001.SS - SSE' limit 1 offset 2", 0), "\d+,\d+\.\d+")*1
```

[image: 0]

or other source:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SHCOMP:IND/", 
 "//span[@class = 'priceText__1853e8a5']")*1
```

[image: 0]

Comment: The one I am referring to is SSE Composite Index (China). The one shown in your example is a company in scotland.
Current value of SSE Composite is 2660.xx

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil I see, try the last one. answer updated

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am trying to generate data from googlefinance using other params too like start date, end date and interval. That way it gets date wise data for me, automatically.

Comment: well if you are after historical data of OHLCV by date then scrapping it from yahoo is still possible

Comment: should be SHA:000001 but it does not work in GS: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5KJq.png

Comment: Yes man, It doesn't work. In fact, none of the SHA indexes work in google finance. :/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time btw :)

Answer (score 0):

GOOGLEFINANCE is only available in English and does not support most international exchanges.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

add sheets extension func

```
function yahooF(ticker) {

 const url = `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/${ticker}?p=${ticker}`;

 const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});

 const contentText = res.getContentText();

 const price = contentText.match(/<fin-streamer(?:.*?)active="">(\d+[,]?[\d\.]+?)<\/fin-streamer>/);  console.log(price[1]);  return price[1];

}
```

[image]
ref: https://www.lido.app/tutorials/yahoo-finance-google-sheets